# Complex Update Sql Statement

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I have two tables one table has an `id` and a `username` the name of the table is `user`. I have another table called `value` that table has an `id` which is to store the id from the `user` table. The table `value`also has a column called `value` and `item_id` which is used to store the item.

I want to write an update statement that updates the following columns within value `id, value, item_id` however the values I have to execute the statement is `username = $username, value = $value and item_id=$item_id` (based on the application)

How can I write an update statement that stores the `id` (username id), `value` and `item_id`

The reason for using an update statement is because that user can change the value within the `value` column at any time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE `value` SET `value` = $value WHERE item_id = $item_id 
AND user_id IN (SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE username = $username)
```

be sure to sanitize your database inputs.

this will only update, if you want to create the entry (i assume that user_id and item_id are the combined primary key of your second table), you can use a replace into statement.

please tell me if you need that, because i think it was not the question.

it may be not as efficient but i think that will not really matter, but you can of course fetch the user id first with a separate query.

this will probably be better understandable.

Comment: when you say it will only update, does that mean that in the first instance it will not insert it into the table? If that is the case I need the code to update insert the value if it is not there initially

Comment: This doesn't work it seems there is an error in the update statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE value, user
SET value = $value
WHERE item_id = $item_id
AND value.user_id = user.user_id
AND user.username = $username;
```